# No visible @interface for 'MPMediaItem' declares the selector 'representativeItem'

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

I have the following code on my AlbumViewController.h

```
@property MPMediaItemCollection *album;
```

And on my .m I use this property like this:

```
MPMediaItem *item = [[_album.items objectAtIndex:i] representativeItem];
```

On Xcode 6.0 this code compiles just fine, but on Xcode 7.0 I keep getting the "No visible interface" error.

Does anybody knows how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want:

```
MPMediaItem *item = _album.items[i];
```

The `items` method of `MPMediaItemCollection` returns an `NSArray` of `MPMediaItem` objects.

The `representativeItem` property is a property of `MPMediaItemCollection`, not `MPMediaItem`, hence the error.

The code compiled on Xcode 6 because `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id` and you can call any method on an `id`. With Xcode 7 (really iOS 9), the array is defined as being an array of type `MPMediaItem` so the compiler now knows the type in the array and better error checking can be performed at compile time.

BTW - even though the code compiled under Xcode 6, it would have crashed at runtime.